# Cloudformation template to create multiple SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I am trying to create 2 SQS using a single cloudformation template. I want to apply same Queue policy to both the queues. Currently I have the below template to create 1 queue and its corresponding dlq. Do I have to write all the resources twice or can I reuse the same queue policy for Queue2?

```yaml
Resources:
  Queue1:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt   DeadLetterQueue.Arn
        maxReceiveCount: 10
      QueueName: queue1
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 604800
      VisibilityTimeout: 150
      ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 0

  DeadLetterQueue1:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: queue1-dlq
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600

  QueuePolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: allow-service-to-read-and-write-messages
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/User
            Resource: !GetAtt Queue1.Arn
            Action:
              - SQS:ChangeMessageVisibility
              - SQS:DeleteMessage
              - SQS:GetQueueUrl
              - SQS:ReceiveMessage
              - SQS:SendMessage
      Queues:
        - !Ref Queue1

  DeadLetterQueuePolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: allow-service-to-read-messages
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/User
            Resource: !GetAtt DeadLetterQueue1.Arn
            Action:
              - SQS:ChangeMessageVisibility
              - SQS:DeleteMessage
              - SQS:GetQueueUrl
              - SQS:ReceiveMessage
          - Sid: allow-queue-to-send-messages
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: '*'
            Resource: !GetAtt DeadLetterQueue1.Arn
            Action:
              - SQS:SendMessage
            Condition:
              ArnEquals:
                "aws:SourceArn": !Ref Queue1
      Queues:
        - !Ref DeadLetterQueue1

Outputs:
  SourceQueueURL:
    Description: URL of source queue
    Value:
      Ref: Queue1
  SourceQueueARN:
    Value: !GetAtt Queue1.Arn
    Description: Arn of created SQS
  DeadLetterQueueURL:
    Description: URL of dead-letter queue
    Value:
      Ref: DeadLetterQueue1
  DeadLetterQueueARN:
    Value: !GetAtt DeadLetterQueue1.Arn
    Description: Arn of created SQS
```

Tried with just 1 queue and its working fine

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the policy separately for the second queue as it will have different `!GetAtt DeadLetterQueue1.Arn`. If you do not want to do this, you can extract the policy to a different template and use that template as a [nested stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html) in your template with queue.